# Namespaces with nested resources Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, namespaces, routes, nested

I'm trying to organize my Rails application into two namespaces that provide the same resources, but with different controllers and views. Something like the following cenario:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :beehives do
    resources :bees
    resources :honeycombs
end

namespace :api do
    resources :beehive, only: [:show] do
        resources :bees, only: [:index, :show]
        resources :honeycombs, only: [:index, :show]
    end
end
```

Using scaffold, I've created the controllers structure:

> rails g controller api/beehives
>
> rails g controller api/beehives/bees
>
> rails g controller api/beehives/honeycombs

And the folder structure I got for controllers sounds like this:

```
+ app
  + controllers
    - beehives_controller.rb
    - bees_controller.rb
    - honeycombs_controller.rb
    + api
      - beehives_controller.rb
      + beehives
        - bees_controller.rb
        - honeycombs_controller.rb
```

**controllers/beehives_controller.rb**

```
class Api::BeehivesController < ApplicationController
```

**controllers/api/beehives_controller.rb**

```
class Api::BeehivesController < ApplicationController
```

**controllers/api/beehives/bees_controller.rb**

```
class Api::Beehives::BeesController < ApplicationController
```

Well, that was easy. In this context, `/beehives/1` will route to root namespace (intended for the web application) and `/api/beehives/1` to the "api" namespace (intended for providing a RESTful webservice). That's working really fine. The problem is when I try to access `/api/beehives/1/bees`, for some reason, the namespacing is not applying to the nested resource and Rails spit this error:

```
uninitialized constant Api::BeesController
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`resources :beehive` + nested `resources :bees` doesn't require your respective controllers to be nested too. It's just a way of constructing URLs. So, it's naturally that your app asks for   `Api::BeesController` instead of `Api::Beehives::BeesController`.

If you have any doubts, use `rake routes` command to check your routes and their associated controllers.

Comment: But hey @jdoe , this broke my folder structure. I had to put the related controllers inside `api` folder, instead of `api/beehives`. That breaks my organization because inside `api` folder I will have more than one resource to provide.

Comment: @DerekWillianStavis `resources` accepts `:module => 'behives'` option. Also you can use `scope :module => 'behives' do ... end` wrapper for your nested resource.

Comment: I thought :module wouldn't work with namespaces, but it does. Thanks a lot!